# Split the input file with line breaks

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to insert line breaks on a file based on the same names which happens to be the second field in my file. So, my input file is like below.

```
17412193|name1|organization
43979400|name1|organization
1405541|name2|organization
53595498|name2|organization
50439202|name2|organization
54678379|name3|Not Found
21757330|name3|organization
```

So I am trying to get the output like,

```
17412193|name1|organization
43979400|name1|organization
###linebreak inserted here
1405541|name2|organization
53595498|name2|organization
50439202|name2|organization
###linebreak inserted here
54678379|name3|Not Found
21757330|name3|organization
###linebreak inserted here
```

I am using this line break to split the input file to group the similar names together. I would later apply a similarity algorithm on these grouped names. So, for the above example, after the output I would apply the similarity algorithm on 3 pairs of names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your file is sorted/grouped by the 2nd field already

```
awk -F '|' 'NR>1 && $2 != prev {print ""} {prev=$2; print}' file
```

Comment: It would be helpful to us, if you explain your command.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a case insensitive Perl solution:

```
perl -F'\|' -lape 'unless($F[1]=~/^$pre$/i || $.==1){print ""}; $pre=$F[1]' file
```

**Explanation:**

- The `-a` splits the input lines into the `@F` array, making perl act like awk.
- The `-F` is the field separator
- `-p` means print each input line
- `-l` adds a `\n` to each print call, so `print ""` prints a newline.
- `unless($F[1]=~/^$pre$/i || $.==1)` : Unless the second field is the same as that of the previous line (the `i` in `//i` makes the match case insensitive), or unless this is the first line.
- `$pre=$F[1]` : save this lines second field as `$pre`.

---

@GlennJackman suggested a slightly different version in the comments which will probably be faster for larger files:

```
perl -F'\|' -lape 'unless(lc($F[1]) eq lc($pre) || $.==1){print ""}; $pre=$F[1]' file
```

Comment: @Ramesh you're welcome, I added an explanation of how it works.

Comment: It is really an elegant solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: This seems like regex overkill: `$F[1]=~/^$pre$/i` -- I wonder if this would be simpler: `lc($F[1]) eq lc($pre)`

Comment: Also, `-l` automatically `chomp`s each incoming line, so `print $_` outputs the right number of newlines (one).

Comment: @glennjackman you're probably right. At the very least, using `lc()` would make it faster. It also makes it not fit on the same line in the post though and it's not that big of a difference so I'll leave it. Not sure what you mean about `-l`, yes it does imply `chomp()` but why is that relevant?

Comment: @glennjackman ah, I think I see, you mean because I've set `$/ = '\n\n'` so it would print two newlines at the end without it. Indeed, good point thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A little shorter Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'print "\n" if ($l =~ /name\d+/ && $_ !~ /$&/);$l=$_;' input
```

- if last line (`$l`) was `name\d+` and current line not last match, then print new line
- assign current line to `$l`

A more general solution

```
perl -pe 'print "\n" if ($l =~ /\|([^\|]+)/ && $_ !~ /$1/);$l=$_;'  input
```

Comment: Heh, +1 for the clever matching but I don't think the names the OP has will actually be in the form of `name\d+`. More likely they will be arbitrary strings.

Comment: thanks, yes that's right, I'm thinking about `/\|.*?\|/`, but it seems not to work.

Comment: You need to quote the match because of the `|`: `perl -pe 'print "\n" if ($l =~ /\|.*?\|/ && $_ !~ /"$&"/);$l=$_;'`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
#shell basics, POSIX compliant
(set -f ;IFS='|
' ; set -- $(cat) ; while [ -n "$3" ] ;do {
[ "${t=$2}" != "$2" ] && echo && t=$2
printf '%s|%s|%s\n' "$1" "$2" "$3" ; shift 3 
} ; done )<<\SAMPLE
17412193|name1|organization 
43979400|name1|organization 
1405541|name2|organization 
53595498|name2|organization 
50439202|name2|organization 
54678379|name3|Not Found 
21757330|name3|organization
SAMPLE

Output

17412193|name1|organization 
43979400|name1|organization 

1405541|name2|organization 
53595498|name2|organization 
50439202|name2|organization 

54678379|name3|Not Found 
21757330|name3|organization
```